# Multiple Tab Validation is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

When I click the submit button the multiple tab validation is not working. I have around 12 tabs. If I click Submit button within any tab it simply submitted. The other tabs are not getting validated.

```js
 $("#btn-login").click(function () {
        var IsValid = true;

        // Validate Each Bootstrap tab
        $(".tab-content").find("div.tab-pane").each(function (index, tab) {
            var id = $(tab).attr("id");
            alert(id);
            //$('a[href="#' + id + '"]').click(function (e) {
            //    e.preventDefault();
            //    $(this).tab('show');
            //});
            $('a[href="#' + id + '"]').tab('show');
            //$('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + id + '"]').tab('show');
            //alert($('a[href="#' + id + '"]').attr("href") + " 2345");
            alert("succ11");
            var IsTabValid = $("#" + id).validate();
           
            alert("succ12");
            if (IsTabValid.valid()) {
                alert(id + " success");
                IsValid = false;
            }
        });

    });
```

```html
 <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style=" padding-left:0px; padding-right:0px;">
                    <div class="tabs-left" style="padding-top: 0px; margin-top: 0px;">
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tabs">
                            <li id="hm" class="active"><a href="#status" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#status"><span class="icon-time" style="color: white; font-size: 15px"></span></a></li>
                            <li id="edu"><a href="#passport" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#passport"><span class="icon-globe" style="color: white; font-size: 15px"></span></a></li>
                            <li id="pro"><a href="#movement" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#movement"><span class="icon-move" style="color: white; font-size: 15px"></span></a></li>
...
...
...
...
</div>
</div>


 <div class="modal-footer" style="padding-bottom: 0px; margin-top:10px;">
                                        <input type="submit" id="btn-login" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit" />
                               
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger modal-close-btn" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                       </div>
```

Comment: Please post the HTML Code with  id="btn-login", It will be better if you create a JsFiddle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using jquery.validation, then you are probably hitting the fact that by default, it only validates visible controls.

you can change this before by using something like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("form").validate().settings.ignore = "";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, jquery validation is not working for hidden fields(like hidden tab also).
To enable this add this code out of the ready method

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
            ignore: []
   });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var dataForm = $('#form');
dataForm.mage('validation', {"ignore": ""});
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your code to improve the answer's quality. Code-only answers are not particularly useful.